# No program line for ConcurrentodificationException

Tags: jmap, jmapviewer

I need to use JMapViewer to display an image in to map but when I update the map I obtain

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.JMapViewer.paintComponent(JMapViewer.java:617)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I know what ConcurrentModificationException means but why in the exception there isn't the line of my program that throws this exception?Anyone can help me?

Comment: Any code you can show us?

Comment: are you removing elements from the list in an enhanced for loop (`for(Something something : somethings) { somethings.remove(something); }`)? Because that throws this exception.

Comment: technically the problem seems to be in `at org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.JMapViewer.paintComponent(JMapViewer.java:617)` can you debug that somehow if the sources are given?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating through a list, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Comment: trashgod, I don't think this post is duplicate of  Iterating through a list, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop because this post is specific to JMapViewer and the other one is about removing items from a collection. By the way, I'm facing the same problem. As @EpicPandaForce asked, I'm using a loop to remove marks from the map. Is there a fix?